# How to change a global var in an if statement and then reuse that change in another if statement?

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I'm running a game.js file in a Perlenspiel engine. I have a global variable called

```
var hasKey;
```

In the PS.keyDown = function I'm running this

```
var hasKey;
    if(dataAtScout == "key"){
        hasKey = true;
        PS.audioPlay("fx_jump8");
        PS.debug("Scout has picked up an odd key")
    }

    if(dataAtScout == "exit"){
        Scout.x = oldSX;
        Scout.y = oldSY;
        PS.debug("\nTheres a computer at the door.")

        if(hasKey == true){
            PS.debug("\nThe door creaks open as Scout runs into a cornfield.")

        }
        else{
            PS.debug("\nError... Error... Error... Error")
        }

    }
```

I'm wanting to check if the key has been picked up while the player is at the exit. However, I am not able to do so. I've tried many, many things and this is the last hurdle that is stumping me. I want to change hasKey = true globally so that when dataAtScout = "exit" it will confirm that the variable has changed to true. So, in my dataAtScout = "key", how can I changed the hasKey variable to true, globally, to be confirmed later by another if statement?

I saw another post with a similar question and the conclusion was that a reset(); needed to be called. I tried that but it didn't work.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you put `var hasKey` inside the function, that declares a new local variable that is only scoped to the function and only lasts for the duration of the function.  Its local declaration then hides the globally declared one from access within the function.  Remove the `var hasKey` from within the function and leave only the globally declared one.

Answer (score 1):

You stated: "In the PS.keyDown = function I'm running this", and then: `var hasKey;`, from which I understand that the code you are showing is the body or part of the body of the function aforementioned, therefore your `hasKey` variable is local to this function.

Remove the `var hasKey;` (from inside your function) statement to use the global variable.

PS. disclaimer: you should never use global variables.

Comment: I have the variable in my global section and above the if. Should I remove both? By the way, thank you!

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I'm running off 6 hrs of sleep in three days / two nights and having to write 1400 lines. Honestly, thank you!

Comment: No offense but you probably should review the absolute JavaScript fundamentals before writing anything... anyway good luck.

Comment: I'm in a programming class at Full Sail. No offense taken. Something so remedial shouldn't have been as much of a challenge as it was. I'm learning and doing at the same time and that can be a bit overwhelming. Also, the 1400 lines of my game.js are working, flawlessly.